# How do I convert dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to dd-mm-yy hh:mm in excel?

Tags: excel-2010, excel-2007

How do I convert `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` to `dd-mm-yy hh:mm` in Excel? Means `20/12/2015 16:19:53` to `20-12-16 16:19`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to excel
2. Select the Cell in which you have entered the Date and time
3. Press Ctrl + 1 , Format Cells window will open.
4. Go to "Number" tab
5. In that Go to "Date" option.
6. Select the "Type" like "04-12-2003" Whatever the way you want represent your date.
7. Similar for Time which is just listed below Date only

Hope this helps

Comment: what opens when you press CTRL+1? You are getting open a Format Cell window or not? Make sure you did select the cell in which date is written

Comment: Yes, format cell window is open. I did it but could not changed the format. Can you write what are possible reasons it could not work.

Comment: Are you writing the date by yourself in excel or getting it from somewhere else like Pressing "CTRL+ ;" ?

Answer (score 0):

You just added your custom format like `dd-mm-yy hh:mm`.

Right click on the excel sheet, select the option `Formating cells`, select `Custom` option and place your format and save it.